# Could not select profile for comment on blogger blog

Tags: blogger

I tried to leave a comment on blogger blog. But I can not select my profile because that Combo box is empty. (Unfortunately I can not attach screenshot :()

Note that this problem only occurs when I try on my company PC. It is not on my home PC. is it due to some security reason?

Thanking you.!

Comment: are you using Google+ or blogger comments?

Comment: can you share your blog url

Comment: Thanks for replying me. Actually this is not a problem of particular URL. Problem occurs in all blogspot blogs.

Comment: Note that this profile selection problem only occurs in company PC. not in my home PC.T

Comment: Perhaps yes.Your Company's site blocks other various sites as well,right?then yes